# How to use select within map for a list of dataframes

Tags: r, purrr

I have a list of dataframes each with the same columns. I want to drop some columns by index. How do I use a select command within a map function?

Here is my attempt:

```
data <- data %>% map(~ select(-c(7, 11, 13, 14)))
```

Any ideas on how I need to change this code?

Many thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try :

```
data <- purrr::map(data, ~ . %>% dplyr::select(-c(7, 11, 13, 14)))
```

Or in base R :

```
data <- lapply(data, function(x) x[,-c(7, 11, 13, 14)])
```

#### Update

This worked for me with `dplyr > 0.8`

```
data <- map(data, .f = list(. %>% dplyr::select(-grp)))
```

Comment: This should be  ```map(data, ~ .x %>% select(FOO)```

Answer (score 1):

We can do this without anonymous function

```
data <- lapply(data, `[`, -c(7, 11, 13, 14))
```